# Making a new column in a data frame with data from a longer data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames of unequal length. df1 is significant genes from an analysis, around len=200. It looks like this:

```
Gene_Name     P.Value
gene1          1E-15
gene17         1E-14
gene400        5E-14
etc
```

The df2 is a list of all the known genes in the species I study and their closest homolog in *Arabidopsis*, len>>>>200. It looks like this:

```
Gene_Name     Homolog_Name
gene1          Arabid_g1
gene2          Arabid_g2
gene3          Arabid_g3
etc
```

I would like to add a column to df1 from the "Homolog_Name" column from df2, but only for the 200 genes in df1, ending with a result like:

```
Gene_Name     P.Value     Homolog_Name
gene1          1E-15       Arabid_g1
gene17         1E-14       Arabid_g17
gene400        5E-14      Arabid_g400
etc
```

I'm not sure how to do this when df lengths are different, does anyone have a suggestion?